# How to call a Sub without knowing which form is loaded into panel?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

On every `DataGridView1_SelectionChanged` event I need to run a `Private Sub OnSelectionChanged()` of the form that is loaded into Panel1 (see the image http://tinypic.com/r/2nu2wx/8).

Every form that can be loaded into Panel1 has the same `Private Sub OnSelectionChanged()` that initiates all the necessary calculations. For instance, I can load a form that calculates temperatures or I can load a form that calculates voltages. If different element is selected in the main form’s DataGridView1, either temperatures or voltages should be recalculated.

The problem is - there are many forms that can be loaded into Panel1, and I’m struggling to raise an event that would fire only once and would run the necessary Sub only in the loaded form.

Currently I’m using `Shared Event`:

```
'Main form (Form1).
Shared Event event_UpdateLoadedForm(ByVal frm_name As String)

'This is how I load forms into a panel (in this case frm_SCT).
Private Sub mnu_SCT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mnu_SCT.Click
    frm_SCT.TopLevel = False
    frm_SCT.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Panel1.Controls.Add(frm_SCT)
    frm_SCT.Show()
    Var._loadedForm = frm_SCT.Name
    RaiseEvent event_UpdateLoadedForm(Var._loadedForm)
End Sub

‘Form that is loaded into panel (Form2 or Form3 or Form4...).
Private WithEvents myEvent As New Form1

Private Sub OnEvent(ByVal frm_name As String) Handles myEvent.event_UpdateLoadedForm
    ‘Avoid executing code for the form that is not loaded.
    If frm_name <> Me.Name Then Exit Sub
End Sub
```

This approach is working but I’m sure it can be done way better (I'd be thankful for any suggestions). I have tried to raise an event in the main form like this:

```
Public Event MyEvent As EventHandler

Protected Overridable Sub OnChange(e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent MyEvent(Me, e)
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    OnChange(EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub
```

but I don't know to subscribe to it in the loaded form.

Thank you.

Comment: You have a contract, every Form derived class needs to provide an OnSelectionChanged method.  You enforce a contract by writing an interface.  And have every form class implement it.  Now it is simple.

Comment: This seemed a very logical approach and I already tried it. To test it I created an interface MyInterface.vb with just one line: Sub ShowMessageBox(). Every form that implemented this interface required to have such subroutine. So far, so good.  But I still couldn’t figure out how to run this subroutine from DataGridView_SelectionChanged event (DataGridView is on the main form). Could you please show some simple pseudocode how to achieve that? Thank you.

Comment: Cast the form object to the interface type with DirectCast.  Or TryCast if you want to flexible.  Your variable, tracking whatever is loaded in the panel, should be either of type Form or the interface type.  Don't forget to dispose replaced forms.

Comment: Thank you, Hans. I was able to achieve what I wanted. I just don’t know how to accept your answer which is posted as a comment.

Comment: Just post the solution yourself and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking into account Hans Passant’s comments as well as code he posted in related thread I achieved what I wanted (see the code below).

```
Public Interface IOnEvent
    Sub OnSelectionChange()
End Interface

Public Class Form1    
    ' ???
    Private myInterface As IOnEvent = Nothing

    ' Create and load form.
    Private Sub DisplayForm(frm_Name As String)

        ' Exit if the form is already displayed.
        If Panel1.Controls.Count > 0 AndAlso _
            Panel1.Controls(0).GetType().Name = frm_Name Then Exit Sub

        ' Dispose previous form.
        Do While Panel1.Controls.Count > 0
            Panel1.Controls(0).Dispose()
        Loop

        ' Create form by its full name.
        Dim T As Type = Type.GetType("Namespace." & frm_Name)
        Dim frm As Form = CType(Activator.CreateInstance(T), Form)

        ' Load form into the panel.
        frm.TopLevel = False
        frm.Visible = True
        frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        Panel1.Controls.Add(frm)

        ' ???
        myInterface = DirectCast(frm, IOnEvent)

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
        Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged

        ' Avoid error if the panel is empty.
        If myInterface Is Nothing Then Return

        ' Run subroutine in the loaded form.
        myInterface.OnSelectionChange()

    End Sub
End Class
```

One last thing – it would be great if someone could take a quick look at the code (it works) and confirm that it is ok, especially the lines marked with “???” (I don’t understand them yet).